# Does a macro allocate memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, macros

Does a macro allocate memory in a segment? If yes, in which memory segment `NUMBER` is stored?

```
#define NUMBER 10
```

Comment: From: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros. _"An object-like macro is a simple identifier which will be replaced by a code fragment...then the C preprocessor will recognize and expand the macro...C compiler will see the same tokens as it would if you had written"_

Comment: `NUMBER` allocates dynamic memory at compile time (in compiler's heap). There is no allocation in compiled program - at least not for the macro.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic it will occupy memory into `.text` ([code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment)) section. ;) For each time is it used in code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261207/how-memory-is-allocated-to-macros-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, macros don't work like that.

They are substituted by the *preprocessor*. The *compiler* doesn't get to see `NUMBER`. All it will see is the literal `10`.

In this respect, C and C++ are identical.

Answer (score 3):

No memory is allocated for the macro. When compiling the code, the macro is mechanically replaced with its value in all places it is used.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, Macro does not allocate the memory.

These statements are not like variable assignment, no memory is allocated. Remember, the **preprocessor** acts before compilation.

`NUMBER` is relevant only in `pre-processing` stage and does not have any identity at run time. During pre-processing all instances of `NUMBER` are replaced with 10. so there is no memory requirement at run time because 10 is an integer literal(Compile time).

Please, read reference [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/c-program-to-an-executable/).

Answer (score 2):

No, in general, a `#define` directive does not *allocate* any memory as such.

To elaborate, `#define` is a replacement directive. All it does is a textual replacement during the preprocessing stage.

So, a textual code like

```
#define NUMBER 10
.
.
.
if (val == NUMBER)
```

looks like

```
if (val == 10)
```

after preprocessing. So, the MACRO substitution defined by `#define` does not take any separate memory. FWIW, The replacement (literal) value will take up usual place in the code segment (*same as if you've written the later format, with direct litreal value, without a MCARO*).

Related, from C11, chapter §5.1.1.2/ p4, *Translation phases*

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
>   _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. [...]

Answer (score 1):

This define does not allocate memory in your program.

It just tells the preprocessor (part of the compiler) to replace further instances of the token `NUMBER` by `10`.

It probably allocates some bytes in the preprocessor, though.

Answer (score 1):

A `#define` by itself does not take up any memory, what happens is the compiler - during pre-compilation stage - replaces all occurrences of NUMBER in your code with the definition, in your case 10.